# Paypal where to set accept digital goods payment in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been trying this for few days. I've created some seller accounts, one of them I created early this year and it was working fine. Then when I return for this project this March, Paypal changed the API from x.com to developer.paypal.com. The old seller accounts were still working fine and can still accept the digital goods payments from the payer accounts that I created recently, however the new seller accounts, with BUSINESS type, suppose to be able to pay and accept payments got some issues. These newly created seller accounts receive the following warning:

> You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.﻿

Doing some research with google, I released I have to set the paypal business account for digital goods. But I can't find where to set it from the new paypal developer control panel. Even when I tried to log in to the sandbox version of paypal.com, using the seller accounts I created in the sandbox, I still can't find where I can set it. In my business setup, there are only two options for me, one is Paypal payments pro and other other is "Virtual Terminal". Any idea? Please help....

Answer (score 3):

I've found the way to add express checkout for digital goods in sandbox, but I think Paypal should pay attention to this because the way I used was very clumsy.

First sign in to sandbox and choose a business account to log in to the sandbox by using the url provided in the Application/Sanbox Accounts. Then use the account that you want to set to accept digital goods checkout to log into the sandbox url, it should be www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/home

After logged in, go to my business setup and pay attention to the setup my payment solution. Click the view all products and you will be redirected to a new page. Please note the url now, the "sandbox" is missing. Now click on the express checkout button, or whatever you want to add to the payment solution, you will be redirected again. Now pay attention to the url, insert "sandbox" to the url, e.g www.paypal.com you have to replace it with www.sandbox.paypal.com, the rest of the url remain the same. Then press enter you will be redirected back to the business setup page. Now you can see your payment solution has become express checkout. It is stupid and I hope paypal can let us choose this directly from the control panel in the near future.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.  I ran through similar process - updated my acct to business, went to my business setup in the right bar, click 'start now' in Set up my payment solution box, had to doctor the url to be sanbox as opposed to sandbox3, and then went to the FOOTER of the site in GREY writing and found 'express checkout'.  Click that, and click the blue Get Started button with a phone number underneath.  This set payment solution to Express Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative hides in Profile > My selling tools > API access > Update > At the bottom - Enable Express Checkout.

When I later go to My Account > My Business Setup I see: "Your payment solution: PayPal Digital Goods (Express Checkout)"